# How to integrate Azure Mobile services with existing android app

Tags: android, azure, azure-mobile-services

I am developing an android app and want to use azure mobile services.
The Azure portal provides all details regarding Azure subscriptions and creating remote database and also provides a sample app for testing purpose. But how should I use it with my existing Android project? Do I need to dig out code from the Azure sample Android app and copy it to my Android code or is there any other straight clean way? Help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good starter would be this **Add Mobile Services to an existing app** documentation page: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-ios-get-started-data/

Comment: Here's the Android version of that tutorial: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-android-get-started-data/